# push data from input text to table - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html

I have 2 input text

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name">
<input type="text" ng-model="lastname">
```

I have a table :

```
             <table>
                <thead>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="row in customers">
                        <td>{{row.fname}}</td>
                        <td>{{row.lname}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

I want to push data from name and last name text boxes into a row in the table using angularjs, any help?

Comment: do you have some button which pushes the data into the $scope.customers ?

Comment: yes, a button calling a function and stuck here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller create a function which will store customer in customers array.

in template

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name">
<input type="text" ng-model="lastname">
<button ng-click="addCustomer(name, lastname)>Add</button>
```

in controller

```
$scope.customers = [];
$scope.addCustomer(name, lastname){
     $scope.customers.push({ fname:name, lname:lastname });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just create a new customer object on the click of a button and push it into the customers array. When you add the customer object, the row shall be created.

```
<button ng-click="createCustomer()">Push</button>
```

In the controller,

```
$scope.createCustomer = function(){
 customers.push(new Customer($scope.name,$scope.lastname));
}

var Customer = function(name,lastname){
 this.fname = name;
 this.lname = lastname;
}
```

Comment: example please ?

Comment: edited the answer for your reference and added the code. By creating a new object of customer and adding it into the array, you tell the ng-repeat in view to add a new row

Comment: the 2 solutions working, but the second one is more close to my code (habits), working thank you !